# How can I get from firebase array of objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I need to get array of objects of sources from firebase grouped by category.
Firebase structure is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGBSS.jpg)

Every authenticated user have its own array of sources.
Security rules for db is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygiqh.jpg)
Every source have array of articles and have category.
I use vuefire to bind to firebase-database. I have written this, but I don't know what I should do next to get all sources grouped by category.

```
var sources=[];
var db=firebase.database();
var id=auth.user().uid;
var userDb=db.ref(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can imagine how to retrieve your data from firebase database if I give you this example:

```
function getData(data) {
    var items = data.val();
    console.log(items, 'myItem') //here is your items that you need
}

function errData(err) {
    console.log('error:', err)
}

const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const result = firebase.database().ref(id);
result.on('value', getData, errData)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood how get data, but I still don't know how group data.

Comment: can you send the response of the data? and how do you want to group it?